# Component identification (SMD)

Tags: diodes, components, surface-mount, identification

Help me identify this component: test results identify it as a diode. I believe the manufacturer is Vishay, but I can't find anything when I search for it. There is a label placed on the component: ".1 J 50-".

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see three components...

Comment: I'd guess the blue one

Comment: Yes it's the blue one.

Comment: A capacitor comes to mind. Can you follow the traces and see where they lead?

Comment: If the IC reads 7612 as I think it doesm it looks like a capacitor connected to V+ and V- with a value of 0.1uF.
Have never seen such 4 pad smd capacitors before though, so not sure.

Comment: A solid MnO2 tantalum capacitor is a MIS diode in reverse bias. It is most probably a solid tantalum capacitor (likely 0.1uF, J the tolerance and perhaps 50V rated).

Comment: @RockfordMan I think it is better that you somehow highlight the  component  of interest when there are more present in your picture, next time.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is its a 50V 0.1uF capacitor (not tantalum or electrolytic, since there are no polarization markings).

The J would denote 5% tolerance of the cap.

With no polarization markings it is not a diode or a polarized cap

I couldn't find a company marking or any other 'blue' capacitors, so I'm a little lost as to where this was sourced from.

Desolder the part from the board and measure it with a 'voltmeter' for impedance and do a capacitance test on it.